# Plot multiple plots corresponding to multiple columns, specified by index, on 1 graph/axes using ggplot2

Tags: r, indexing, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

Here is the data frame:

```
> test
             a           b          c
1   0.22904349 -0.12023869  0.1546898
2   1.09504754 -0.20398923 -0.9313251
3  -0.41200391 -0.16308791  0.6716105
4  -0.04356308 -1.81898245 -0.8074506
5  -1.23413459  1.24309479 -1.3861049
6   0.14266136 -2.22712577 -0.2341793
7  -0.25113445  0.60213281 -0.8106908
8   2.52372557  0.03794341 -1.4308955
9   0.66005867  0.74508029 -0.2922560
10  1.23552452 -0.26187445 -0.9874546
```

What I want to plot are the densities of a,b and c on a single graph. I want to be able to specify the columns to be plotted by their indices. Additionally, the densities can be colored according to their columns. This is the code I tried:

```
test<- as.data.frame(cbind(a=rnorm(1:10),b=rnorm(1:10),c=rnorm(1:10)))
for(i in seq(1,ncol(test),1)){
  if(i==1)p<-ggplot(data=test, aes_string(x=names(test)[i]))
  else p<-p+ggplot(data=test, aes_string(x=names(test)[i]))
}
p+geom_density()
```

Error I got:

```
Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"
```

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Is specifying them by index really a priority? It seems like you think you need to do it because you think you need a for loop, but that's not the case.

Comment: The indexing would make it easier to name the columns if there are many columns. The above data frame is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard ggplot way is to use long data, not wide data:

```
library(tidyr)
test_long = gather(test)

ggplot(test_long, aes(x = value, color = key)) +
    geom_density()
```

If you really want indices in there, we'll add them to the long data:

```
test_long$index = match(test_long$key, names(test))
```

And then the way to select which ones to plot is to subset the data passed to ggplot

```
# if you only want columns 2 and 3 from the original data
ggplot(test_long[test_long$index %in% c(2, 3), ],
       aes(x = value, color = key)) +
    geom_density()
```

And, if you *really* want to be stubborn, the problem with your for loop is that `ggplot` is called multiple times. `ggplot()` initializes a plot, you can't add it to a plot multiple times. You can fix it, but you shouldn't do things this way.

```
p = ggplot(data = test)

for(i in seq_along(test)) {
  if (i == 1) p = p + geom_density(aes_string(x = names(test)[i]))
  else p = p + geom_density(aes_string(x = names(test)[i]), color = "green")
}

print(p)
```

In this case ggplot isn't being used as intended so you'd have to set up your own colors and adding a legend will be a real pain. Which is part of why you should do it the other way, the easy way.

---

Edits: In a fresh R session, this runs just fine for me:

```
# load packages
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# data from the question
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(a=rnorm(1:10),b=rnorm(1:10),c=rnorm(1:10)))

# long format
test_long = gather(test)

# plot all 3
ggplot(test_long, aes(x = value, color = key)) +
    geom_density()

# add original data indices
test_long$index = match(test_long$key, names(test))

# plot only columns 2 and 3
ggplot(test_long[test_long$index %in% c(2, 3), ],
       aes(x = value, color = key)) +
    geom_density()
```

Comment: Hi Gregor, sorry for the late reply. Had some problem installing tidyr and was busy, but now its fine. The first set of code ran fine. However, I have trouble using the 2nd set of code which is for columns 2 and 3. I am getting this error: 
"Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default."

Comment: Did you run the second code block before attempting the plot in the third code block? That's the error you would get if you didn't run the `test_long$index = match(...` line.

Comment: I did run that "test_long$index = match(..." line, and have checked again. The error is still there.

Comment: It works for me in a fresh R session. I put the entire code I ran at the bottom of the question; it's no different than the code above. Try it in a new R session, if it doesn't work maybe make sure your packages are up to date?

Comment: Tried it after updating, somehow it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ggplot2 likes you data to be long, not wide. In this case, we can make your data wide by using the library `tidyr` (or `reshape2`, or `reshape`, or `data.table`)

```
set.seed(1234)
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(a = rnorm(1:10), b = rnorm(1:10), c = rnorm(1:10)))
library(tidyr)

data <- gather(test, letter, value)
```

Take a look at how data is laid out, one measure per row. Now to plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = value, col = letter)) +
       geom_density()
```

[image]